# delete specific folder in root and suborders

Tags: windows-10, batch

I want to delete specific folder in root and suborders, the problem is my code only delete folder in root of directory:

```
SET dirname=test
SET directory=%cd%
SET found=false


    if NOT "%1%" == "" (
        set directory=%1%
    )
    echo Searching for %dirname% in %directory%

    for /d %%i in (%directory%\%dirname%) do (
        IF EXIST %%i (
            REM change the sentinel value
            set found=true

            echo Deleting the folder %%i
            REM Delete a folder, even if not empty, and don't prompt for confirmation
            RD  /s /q %%i
        )
    )

    REM logic to do if no files were found
    if NOT "%found%" == "true" (
        echo No directories were found with the name of %dirname%
    )
```

This is the folder structure:

```
E:sampledelete
├───folder1
├───folder2
│   └───somefolder
├───test
│   └───somefolder
├───newfolder
│   ├───test
│   │   └───somefolder
├───newfolder2
│   ├───test
```

after runing script it changed to:

```
E:sampledelete
├───folder1
├───folder2
│   └───somefolder
├───newfolder
│   ├───test
│   │   └───somefolder
├───newfolder2
│   ├───test
```

Comment: Could you add a TAG to the question with the version of Windows you're using here?

Comment: I use windows 10

Comment: (0) Please [edit] your question to add the [windows 10] tag.  (1) What’s a “suborder”?  (2) Please  [edit] your question to state your problem more clearly.

Comment: @scott I edited it and I tested on windows 7 and windows 10. it dosent work only remove the folder in root directory

Comment: Do you want to keep deleting down the line such as : C:\1nodeDeep\2nodesDeep\3nodesDeep\4nodesDeep\...\test ?

Answer (score 0):

The issues are annotated below. The main issue was directory misconception: you were not looking inside the directory beneath 1 node under root. You had the right idea. Since you are "new" as you said, it would be worth analyzing the differences.

```
@echo off
SET dirname=test
SET directory=%cd%
SET found=false

    if NOT "%1%" == "" (
        set directory=%1%
    )

    REM We want to look in the current directory not in for Z:\test
    for /d %%i in (%directory%*) do (
        echo Searching for %%i\%dirname% in %directory%

        REM We already know the folder existed because "do" ran.
        REM We want to look beneath the root directory
        IF EXIST %%i\%dirname% (
            REM change the sentinel value
            set found=true

            REM we want to delete the nodes beneath not the one in root
            echo Deleting the folder %%i\%dirname%

            REM Delete a folder
            REM we want to delete the nodes beneath not the one in root
            RD  /s /q %%i\%dirname%
        )

        IF %%1 == %dirname% (
            REM change the sentinel value
            set found=true

            REM Delete a folder, even if not empty, and don't prompt for confirmation
            echo Deleting the folder %%i\%dirname%
            RD  /s /q %%i
        )
    )

    REM logic to do if no files were found
    if NOT "%found%" == "true" (
        echo No directories were found with the name of %dirname%
    )
```

Comment: thank you but I want to remove all folder in root and subfolders

Answer (score 0):

You’re misunderstanding what `for /d` does.

```
for /d %%i in (dir1 file1 dir2 file2 dir3 file3) do statement
```

does

- `SET %%i=dir1`
- `statement`
- `SET %%i=dir2`
- `statement`
- `SET %%i=dir3`
- `statement`

The problem is, you’re only saying
`for /d %%i in (dir1) do statement`,
where `dir1` is
`%directory%\%dirname%`. 
You want to use `for /r`, which does a recursive directory search. 
Your loop should look something like

```
    for /r %directory% %%i in (.) do (
        if exist %%i\%dirname% (
            REM change the sentinel value
            set found=true

            echo Deleting the folder %%i\%dirname%
            REM Delete a folder, even if not empty, and don't prompt for confirmation
            RD  /s /q %%i\%dirname%
        )
    )
```

Comment: I wasn't sure that she wanted to do a recursive search, just 1 node below. Just 1 node below a given directory (or in her example root) including that own directory. I did try to ask that, but no response yet.

Comment: what i know is that /r will remove files while /d while remove folders

Comment: I don’t know what you’re saying.  I know that the above batch file works on Windows 7, deleting directories named `test` at all levels of the directory tree.  Are you worried that there might also be *files* named `test`?  I didn’t test for that.

Comment: Well?   Have you tried my answer?   Do you have any problem with how it works?